# Israeli working in the Netherlands for a US company - what's the tax situation?

Tags: taxes, netherlands, usa, foreign-employment, israel

I'm an Israeli expat living in the Netherlands and am likely to start working for a US company (registered in the US and has no presence in the Netherlands nor in Israel). To make things even more complicated, during my first months of employment I may or may not move to Israel and then to the US.

Previously I've been employed in the Netherlands for a couple of years.

My questions are:

- Which institutions of which states do I need to report to about being employed?
- Which states would I pay which taxes / tax-like fees to? (personal revenue tax, national insurance / health insurance, other kinds of tax)

Notes:

- Eventually I will work as an employee. Initially I think I'll work as an employee but I'm not sure. You can make whichever assumption you like or discuss both options.